# DROP and CREATE index at the same time

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

We have table owner name and index owner name mismatch. We need to drop the index as well the constraints associated with it and recreate the same in the particular schema to match index owner and table owner name. We have different column count for each index varying from 1 to 4.
I need to create a procedure for dropping n recreating at the same time.

```
declare
total number(10);
table_name varchar2(255);
index_name varchar2(255);
column_name varchar2(255);
begin
select  a.table_name, a.index_name,count(a.column_name) into table_name, index_name,total
from all_ind_columns a, all_indexes b where a.index_name = b.index_name
and b.table_owner = 'SIM'and b.owner like 'TIM'
group by a.table_name,a.index_name
order by a.table_name,a.index_name,count(a.column_name);
select c.column_name into column_name from all_ind_columns c,all_indexes d 
where c.index_name=d.index_name 
and d.table_owner='SIM' and d.owner like 'TIM';
for i in (select  a.table_name, a.index_name,count(a.column_name) from all_ind_columns a, all_indexes b where a.index_name = b.index_name
and b.table_owner = 'SIM'and b.owner like 'TIM'
group by a.table_name,a.index_name
order by a.table_name,a.index_name,count(a.column_name))
loop
If i.count(a.column_name)=1 then
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Create index'||index_name|| 'on' ||table_name||'('||Column_name||')');
else total>=2
then
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Create index'||index_name|| 'on' ||table_name||'('||Column_name,Column_name||')');
end if;
end loop;
end;
```

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 1):

[DBMS_METADATA](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_metada.htm#ARPLS026) is the official way to regenerate object DDL.  It's usually better than manually creating DDL statements.  There are hundreds of options for creating indexes, `DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL` is the only way to ensure you accurately recreate the object.

```
declare
    v_index_ddl clob;
begin
    for indexes_in_wrong_schema in
    (
        select table_name, index_name
        from all_indexes
        where table_owner = 'SIM' and owner like 'TIM'
    ) loop
        v_index_ddl := dbms_metadata.get_ddl('INDEX', 
            indexes_in_wrong_schema.index_name, 'TIM');
        --Or replace these with "execute immediate" to run instead of print.
        dbms_output.put_line('drop index TIM.'||
            indexes_in_wrong_schema.index_name);
        dbms_output.put_line(replace(v_index_ddl, '"TIM"', '"SIM"'));
    end loop;
end;
/
```

**Privileges**

DBMS_METADATA requires you either have the `SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE` or are executing as the schema owner.  Ask a DBA or other privileged user if they can grant you that role.  Or convert the above PL/SQL block into a function, install the function on the owner's schema, and then `grant execute on new_function to your_user;`.

Comment: Thank you for ur support.Can u please elobarate me dis                                              v_index_ddl := dbms_metadata.get_ddl('INDEX', indexes.index_name, 'TIM');                                                                         and when i ran this query I am getting the following error                     ORA:31603: Object'name' of typeINDEX not found in schema "TIM"

Comment: @SamadRaza See the updated answer with fixed syntax and some more information about DBMS_METADATA.

Comment: i m having some privelge related problem i cannot use dbms_metadata Can you please help me on this with some dynamic query