# TOAD for Oracle, variables for schema/ table names

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I have a list of sql queries that compares several tables between two schemas. 
Is there a way to define variables with schema names? So every month one can update the variables on the top of the script? I'm looking for something like that:

```
define schema_name1="CALC1111";
define schema_name1="CALC2222";
select a.*, b.* 
from &schema_name1.TABLE_1 a left join
&schema_name2.TABLE_1 
on <-- some ON statements -->
```

With best regards,
Andrey

Comment: I don't think you can refer to a database object through a text string which is what your schema_name1 variable is. One way of accomplish the behavior you want though is to have your PL/SQL generate the SQL statement you want in a text script and print and run an "Execute()" command at the end.

Comment: Look into the DBMS_OUTPUT package (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_output.htm#BABJCAJA) and the put_line command. Accessing this package is how TOAD generates the Script tab in each object window. Essentially you'll want to do the same thing but then run the statement afterward. Look at the answer on this question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27318150/drop-and-create-index-at-the-same-time for an example. It lists DDL and you only want DML but it is the same idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if TOAD uses SQL*PLUS syntax for substitution variables, then you should be able to do this already. For example, in SQLDeveloper, I run the following script frequently:

```
set define on;
define t_table=ENTER_TABLE_NAME_HERE;
define t_schema=MYSCHEMA;
create public synonym &t_table for &t_schema..&t_table;
```

Note two things:

- You can use no quotes when defining, the variable will be substituted before the text is parsed, as-is. Double quotes will work fine too, but you'll be actually executing something like `select a.*, b.* from "CALC1111".TABLE_1 a left join ...`
- You'll have to use double period (`..`), because a single period is used to separate a substitution variable from the following text if no whitespace is used, so your current text is resolved to `select a.*, b.* from "CALC1111"TABLE_1 a left join ...` which obviously doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is the best option for me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can solve by creating/dropping public synonyms for the tables you want to compare.

Say you want to compare table T1 on changing schemas, SA, SB, SC, ...
You could define public synonyms like

```
create or replace public synonym T1_origin for SA.T1
create or replace public synonym T1_target for SB.T1
```

and write your queries like

```
select a.*, b.* 
from T1_origin a left join T1_target
on ...
```

Every month you only shoud update your public synonyms to refer to the correct schemas, without changing your queries.

Comment: This probably would work but I think it is a very poor solution from a database maintenance perspective. Synonyms should be static and PUBLIC synonyms should be reserved only for cases where multiple schemas need to refer to a single object.